# How can I modify this regex to match URL's containing @ characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex to find links in strings of text using javascript.

```
/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gi
```

It has served me well and appears quite robust.  However I have recently noticed that (perhaps rightly so) it does not match any urls that contain a `@` character.

While these aren't commonplace, Flickr uses them and I wish to support matching those links.

An example Flickr url that I would like to match:

```
https://www.flickr.com/photos/47574723@N03/13849559654/in/explore-2014-04-14
```

So the question is, how can I modify the above regex to enable it to correctly match url's like the on above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit it to add one `@`

```
(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_@\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@\/?]*)?)(\s+|$)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! My understanding of regex is rudimentary at best and in one as long and complex as this, I was just getting myself lost.  Thanks again, i'll mark it as answered as soon as I am able :)